# iOS optimal performance persistent data solution?

Tags: ios, core-data, fmdb, persistent-storage, realm

I am building a healthKit based app and am wondering how to best save healthKit data persistently.

My current approach is to get the data and save it as attributes of a custom class object and then save it in core data as NSData.

In terms of performance is Realm faster than CoreData?

According to http://qiita.com/moriyaman/items/1a2916f4c2b79e934370 CoreData is apparently slower than FMDB which is slower than Realm. Can someone confirm if this is true even after taking into account faults and indexes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Realm

The question of which persistence product will perform best among the solutions you mentioned is highly dependent on the type/amount/frequency of your data. Since Core Data and FMDB are layers over SQLite, they can't be faster than SQLite by design, but they provide enough convenience to be worthwhile to many users. On the other hand, Realm isn't based on SQLite, but rather its own custom database engine that was designed specifically for modern smartphones. It was designed to strike a better balance between powerful features, simple API without adding a large performance hit.

You can see public benchmarks comparing Realm/SQLite/Core Data/FMDB in Realm's launch blog post here: http://realm.io/news/introducing-realm#fast

Finally, your approach of serializing HealthKit information into NSData using something like NSCoding is going to be terribly inefficient. No matter the persistence solution you choose, you'll be better served by using the serialization built in to those products rather than storing an already serialized data blob.

Comment: "Since Core Data and FMDB are layers over SQLite, they can't be faster than SQLite by design." This is identical to saying "C is built on top of assembly, so any assembly you write will be faster than any C you write, by design." That's simply not true. Naively written assembly can be dramatically slower than naively written C, and naively written SQLite can be dramatically slower than naively written Core Data. SQLite and Core Data approach problems very differently, and it is difficult to directly compare the performance, since each dramatically impacts how you should write your program.

Comment: I absolutely agree that comparing ORMs with relational databases with non-relational databases is definitely not an apples-to-apples comparison and that how a program is written also has a significant impact. And naively written code will always affect performance. Programmer level of understanding and experience with the tools they are using will have a significant impact as well.

Comment: @jpsim Realm backend is based on LMDB? Is it open source like forntends?

Answer (score 4):

As I commented to @jpsim, it is difficult to simply compare the performance of Core Data to lower-level frameworks like FMDB, or differently-abstracted frameworks like Realm. Which approach you choose will dramatically impact how you build your program, which will tend to shuffle the performance problems around to different places.

Core Data and SQLite solve very different problems. SQLite is a relational database. Core Data is an object persistence engine. I'm not an expert on Realm, but it seems to be trying to strike a balance between those two approaches with more low-level control than Core Data affords, but a closer tie-in to the object model than SQLite. The fact that Realm (at least in my impressions of it) gives you more low-level control opens up opportunities for you to optimize things, or to mess things up IMO. That's neither good nor bad, it just makes it hard to apples-to-apples compare them, and particularly makes generic "performance benchmarks" problematic. The question isn't whether it's possible for *someone* to write faster code using engine A vs. engine B. The question is whether *you* will likely write acceptably performant code in each engine, while avoiding bugs, and minimizing development time.

In general, I believe HealthKit data is supposed to be stored in HealthKit in order to protect privacy. You should be careful about storing this data in your own storage anyway. Be particularly aware of [the guidelines about iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#healthkit):

> Apps using the HealthKit framework that store users’ health information in iCloud will be rejected

I don't know how this will impact documents that you store and are then backed-up to iCloud. Just leaving the data in HealthKit is the best way to not have to worry about such problems.

In any case, though, performance is just one axis to consider. You didn't indicate anything to suggest that you have very special performance problems (for example, that you're handling tens of thousands of records, or real-time data, or something like that). So I would focus first on what tool meet your general needs best, and then do some basic experiments to make sure the performance is reasonable, and then optimize as you find issues.